# Как закомментировать кусок кода в VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Недавно перешёл на этот редактор кода, и возникают проблемы с комментированием: раньше работал в Sublime, там всё решалось выделением необходимого куска кода и сочетанием клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

Comment: Устанавливаете расширение "Sublime Text Keymap and Settings Importer", становится так же как и в Sublime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> - закомментировать / раскомментировать.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> расскоментировать

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> закомментировать

Answer (score 1):

У меня так:

VSCod автоматически определяет какого вида комментарий создать:

- HTML - вот в таком виде:        `<!--данные-->`
- CSS - вот в таком виде:         `/*данные*/`

В другом виде, типа "//" и ещё варианты у меня не срабатывают (может кто подскажет).

**Закомментировать / Раскомментировать:**

1.) `ctrl` + `/`

(где "/" - не на цифровом блоке);

- создать новый в любом месте;
- то, что выделено;
- где находится курсор - вся строка данных.

2.)  `shift` + `alt` + `a`

- создать новый в любом месте;
- то, что выделено.

Answer (score 0):

на MacOS что закомментировать код нужно использовать сочетание:

**command + /**

Answer (score 0):

как сказано выше ctrl + / работает, но не при всех комментариях, в некоторых используйте

`ctrl` + `k` + `c` (закомментировать)

`ctrl` + `k` + `u` (раскомментировать)